# Best practice for allowing new classes to be added later?

Tags: python, python-import

I am making a python program for simulating simple electronic circuits, and I'm making the gui in kivy. What would be the best practice for allowing me (or theoretically someone else) to add new types of components (which inherit from the base component class) that the program will allow to be used in circuit building? There would need to be a class with methods and properties for interacting as part of a circuit, and either a kivy file or some other representation for how it would be displayed in the gui.

My first thought was to have a components folder which contained separate folders for each component, each of which would have a python file for the class and a kivy file for the gui representation. However, there doesn't seem to be a good way to import from a file based on its filename and that seems very messy anyway. I imagine this sort of thing is quite common in expandable programs so there must be a better way of doing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like that on the past. The first step is to find out what components have in common:

- A list of nodes
- A function `print_time_domain_analysis` that receives a Conductance Matrix for time domain analysis and returns the same matrix updated with the component's parameters.
- Similar functions for other types of analysis, e.g., `print_frequency_domain_analysis`.
- In your case, a method to print the component on your GUI.

You could end up with something like the following:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class TimeAnalysisComponent(ABC):

    def __init__(self, nodes):
        self.nodes = nodes
        super().__init__()

    @abstractmethod
    def print_time_domain_analysis(
        self,
        conductance_matrix,
        current_vector,
        delta_t):
        """
        Prints the component's parameters on a Conductance Matrix and on its
        Current Vector for time domain analysis
        """
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def print_component_on_gui(self, gui_stuff):
        """
        Prints component on GUI.
        """
        pass
```

Then other people would be able to create new components by sub-classing TimeAnalysisComponent and implementing its abstract methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, where I use `args` and `kwargs` to make the code much more DRY. I make a single base class with parameters that all others can inherit from.

So all components have a resistance, so you could have that as an argument in the base class and never have to repeat it in other classes that inherit from it.

```
class Mammal(object):
    def __init__(self, genus, species, agility, *extra_args, **extra_kwargs):
        #extra is ignored as the subclasses handle them differently
        self.species = species
        self.genus = genus
        self.agility = agility

    def speak(self):
        print("Generic {0} making generic {0} sounds".format(self.genus + " " + self.species))

class Human(Mammal):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): #DRYer that re-listing the parameters
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) #Call init of Mammal
        self.intelligence = args[-1] #Uses args

class Hedgehog(Mammal):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.spikiness = kwargs["spikiness"] #Uses kwargs

stephen_hawking = Human("Homo", "Sapiens", 1, 100)
#100 is added to args and handled with self.intelligence = args[-1]
sanic = Hedgehog("Erinaceus", "Europaeus", (2 ** 63) - 1, spikiness = 10)
```

So, for the human, I have added an extra argument that is specific to the human class, intelligence. It is added by simply adding another argument to the initialisation and handling it in `Human.__init__`.
For the hedgehog, I have added an extra keyword argument, which is handled by getting the value of the key `spikiness`. Both of these can be used in conjunction. If I wanted, I could instead make a class `PricklyMammal` with `spikiness` added and make a `Porcupine`, `Hedgehog` and `Cactus` inherit from it, all of which will have the default arguments and keyword arguments of `PricklyMammal`: Those from `Mammal` and the extra ones I have added to `PricklyMammal`

I don't know how much you know about this so sorry if some of it was a bit patronising, but I hope that this helps!

*P.S. No offence, Steven Hawking. We love you.*

Comment: Thanks for your response!
However, that isn't what I am asking about. I know how to do class inheritance. I am looking for a way to store added classes that is easy to access but easy to add to